# Redux in npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, react-hooks

I have been working on my own UI lib as npm package and some of components use Redux. I register components to store as usually, but there occur an error, which looks like:

```
could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

For demonstration purposes, I minified that
UI lib

```
// index.js
export * from './store/reducers'
export { default as MyComponent } from './components/MyComponent'
```

```
// MyComponent.js
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
const MyComponent = () => {
    const pageRemounter = useSelector(state => state.pageRemounter)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const handleClick = () => {
        dispatch({type: "PAGE_REMOUNT"})
    }
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
            <div>
                {
                    pageRemounter ? "Yes" : "No"
                }
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default MyComponent
```

```
// reducer.js
export const pageRemounter = (state=false, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "PAGE_REMOUNT":
            return !state

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /nodeModules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        react: {
            root: 'React',
            commonjs2: 'react',
            commonjs: 'react',
            amd: 'react'
        },
        'react-dom': {
            root: 'ReactDOM',
            commonjs2: 'react-dom',
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            amd: 'react-dom'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './build'
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-maps'
};
```

In random app which use MyComponent

```
// store.js
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { 
    pageRemounter
} from 'mypackage'


const allReducers = combineReducers(
    { 
        pageRemounter
    }
)

const store = createStore(allReducers)

export default store
```

```
// index.js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'

import { MyComponent } from 'myownlib'


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <MyComponent />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Btw there was problem with hooks, so in webpack.config.js was added extarnals.

Comment: When does this error occur?

Comment: When try render component "MyComponent"

Comment: Do you run any build command in "mypackage"? The Provider must run before any other component, so I guess your "mypackage" is built before used?

Comment: I build mypackage by run "react-scripts build", then publish it into registry and then pull it into random app.

Comment: Sory I look into wrong window. I build it by "build": "webpack".

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found solution.
Absolutely remove Webpack and just feed Babel.

```
$ npm install @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
              "useBuiltIns": "entry"
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir dist
```

Now it's ready to publish into npm registry.

Comment: so previously you were bundling your library. And bundle got own local instance of React-Redux, with referentially different context. While current config just transpiles your library but does not bundle every dependecy. Btw, ensure your lib package lists `react-redux` as `peerDependency` not as `dependency`. Otherwise things might work only until target project which imports your ui packages uses the same version of `react-redux` but may break later

Comment: @skyboyer yes, thats true. I figure out that when I added scss. Solution with peerDependecy also doesn't work. I spend much time googling "create react component library with redux" and now I am little bit frustrated, because I can't find anything like that. But if you have some project like my case, could you help me, please?

Comment: not sure what might be the issue with SCSS. You just need to transpile it into plain CSS and publish(I mean `npm publish`) JS files after Babel + CSS files after compilation from SCSS. putting `react-redux` into `peerDependencies` is orthogonal thing, anyway you should do Babel/SCSS compilation _instead_ of webpack/bundling. Publishing bundle is bad for many reasons, and having different instances of(logically) the same contexts is only one of them.

Comment: Yes I created list with possible solutions and that's one of them. But again, I cant find any tutorial for that. Do you know some? I know that's sounds stupid, but when I look for something for a really long time and I can't find a way to it, then I feel like I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: no, I don't have any ready-to-use guide on this.

Comment: while googling I saw articles that say it's ok to use wepback/rollup/other bundles, but I have not found specifically how to configure that some packages would not be bundled. So maybe there is a way, by some special configuration.

Comment: YES, I found it too, but no tutorial for it :(. Maybe another time.

Comment: try to play with `externals`: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/ has some examples. Before reading this I was thinking that `externals` works only to global variable like `window.jQuery` or `window.React`. But probably it may work to npm packages in host project as well